# Single page javascript framework

Tags: javascript

For a project I need to make a modular system for a 1 page only - multi pane - information homepage. Each pane gets his data from a (different) remote json API. These panes need to be modular so they can be exchanged between multiple setups.

Is there a javascript framework that I can use or extend to start with? Up until now I have found http://scaleapp.org that looks promising.

Comment: I don't think your "one-pageness" is actually that specific. Most frameworks out there should be able to handle it fine so you will need to choose between them on other merits.

Comment: @missingno I know but I am looking for something specific that I could start of if it existed.

Answer (score 0):

Many frameworks, like you said.

- dojo
- sencha touch
- jquery mobile

The items above are for smart phones and are based on HTML5.

The project "Scaleapp" seems very interesting.

Comment: FTFY ... Please use basic punctuation and capitalisation next time.

Comment: Capitalisation and punctuation is not specific to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to implement something substantial, I would recommend study a bit more on other concerns in large scale javascript applications.

- How you should organize the code structure
- How to create a hierarchy of functional modules
- How to make UI components self contained
- How to do routing, bookmarking, history handling
- How to manage JS scripts and dependencies
- How to optimize, obfuscate for deployment
- How to make your components unit testable
- How to deal with styling, localization aspects

I have shared experience I gained in some large scale projects in a reference architecture at http://boilerplatejs.org. It addresses all above concerns and provides a sample implementation for someone to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [Pajerjs](http://oscar.finnsson.nu/pagerjs/).   It uses Knockout.js and other frameworks.